Flutter BloC how to ensure multi bloc execute finished?
In my app, I want to init many bloc with calling api to get the data after user login. I need to ensure each bloc finish the API call and get the data.
I try below code to reach my goal, is any smart idea for this situation?
The example code use stupid idea local variable to check the status.
Thank you!!!

class HomeBlocView extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  HomeBlocView({
    required this.child,
  });

  @override
  State<HomeBlocView> createState() => HomeBlocViewState();
}

class HomeBlocViewState extends State<HomeBlocView> {
  bool isGetUser = false;
  bool isGetReservation = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocListener(
      listeners: [
        BlocListener<LoginCubit, LoginState>(
          listenWhen: (previous, current) =>
              previous.authStatus != current.authStatus,
          listener: (BuildContext context, state) {
            switch (state.authStatus) {
              case AuthStatus.authenticated:
                print('------------------login success');
                break;
              case AuthStatus.unauthenticated:
                print('------------------login failure');
                MyGoRouter.go(context, "/login");
                break;
              default:
            }
          },
        ),
        BlocListener<UserCubit, UserState>(
          listener: (BuildContext context, state) {
            switch (state.status) {
              case BlocStatus.failure:
                print('------------------user failure');
                break;
              case BlocStatus.initial:
                print('------------------user success');
                setState(() {
                  isGetUser = true;
                });
                go_to_next();
                break;
              default:
            }
          },
        ),
        BlocListener<ReservationCubit, ReservationState>(
          listener: (BuildContext context, state) {
            switch (state.status) {
              case BlocStatus.failure:
                print('------------------reservation failure');
                break;
              case BlocStatus.initial:
                print('------------------reservation success');
                setState(() {
                  isGetReservation = true;
                });
                go_to_next();

                break;
              default:
            }
          },
        ),
      ],
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }

  go_to_next() {
    if (isGetUser && isGetReservation) {
      MyGoRouter.push(context, "/home/reservation");
    }
  }
}


To summarize your problem, you need some easy way to read states from multiple blocs, without too much boilerplate code.
Check out the following code.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc';

class CustomMultiBlocListener extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomMultiBlocListener({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var authState = context.read<LoginCubit>().state;
    var userState = context.read<UserCubit>().state;
    var reservationState = context.read<ReservationCubit>().state;

    if (authState.authStatus == AuthStatus.unauthenticated) {
      // Redirect to login page here.
      return;
    }

    if (userState.status != BlocStatus.initial) {
      // Handle user data not valid.
      return;
    }

    if (reservationState.status != BlocStatus.initial) {
      // Handle reservation status not valid
      return;
    }

    // Finally, it comes here when all conditions are satisfied
    MyGoRouter.push(context, "/home/reservation");

    return const Placeholder();
  }
}


Inside the build method of this widget, we read the state of all the blocs one-by-one using the context.read<BlocName>() method.
This method is not directly available on the context, so always ensure that flutter_bloc has been imported.
The context.read method returns the state of the bloc at the time when the function has been called.
Unlike the BlocBuilder or BlocListener widgets, which rebuild everytime the state changes, context.read returns the state at the time it was called, and further updates to the state are lost.
If you want to listen to state changes, you can use the context.watch<BlocName> method instead.
Flutter Bloc Docs - context.read
Flutter Bloc Docs - context.watch
